# expanding the width of drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to increase the width of drop down menu...
when you hover over the services link a drop down menu pop up appears....
in this pop up i have included the text fields so i need to increase the width of the drop down menu....
i tried increasing the width of sub class all form fields becomes inline but not working....
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/3VBQ6/1/embedded/result/

```
<ul class="sub">
    <li><a href="#nogo23"><span class='label'>Name</span>
        <span><input type="text" name="lastname" /></span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#nogo24">Company <span><input type="text" name="lastname" /></span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#nogo25">Email <span><input type="text" name="lastname" /></span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#nogo25"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: #nav li:hover ul.sub
    {left:1px; top:38px; background: #bbd37e; padding:3px; border:1px solid #5c731e; white-space:nowrap; width:90px; height:auto; z-index:300;}

Answer (score 0):

try to change the `ul` and `li` width to auto and add a `min-width:90px`

like this:

```
#nav li:hover ul.sub {
   left:1px;
   top:38px;
   background: #bbd37e;
   padding:3px;
   border:1px solid #5c731e;
   white-space:nowrap;
   width: auto;
   min-width:90px;
   height:auto;
   z-index:300;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li {
   display:block;
   height:20px;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   width: auto;
   min-width:90px;
   font-weight:normal;
}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a {
   display:block;
   font-size:11px;
   height:18px;
   width: auto;
   min-width:90px;
   line-height:18px;
   text-indent:5px;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
   border:1px solid #bbd37e;
}
```

Also I added some styles for the input fields

```
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a input {
   font-size:11px;
   height:18px;
   width: auto;
   min-width:90px;
   line-height:18px;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got hard coded widths for all the submenus which you do not need.

If you remove all the widths and the `float:left;` item from 'ul.sub li' which is not needed

You can target that specific menu item by adding a class to it you can adjust just that item via CSS.

```
#nav li:hover ul.sub.frm { width: 155px; }
.frm a .label { display: inline-block; width: 60px; }
.frm a input[type="text"] { width: 80px; }
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/3VBQ6/3/)